# Alternatives to the Pipes and Filters pattern

Tags: design-patterns, pipes-filters

Modifying and tying to test the 7th filter out of a chain of 11 filters proves to be painful to test. I have to do an integration test from Filter#1 to Filter #11 to make sure Filter#7 works properly.

Each filter passes along the same object reference and they work on it.
So for me, I have no idea what kind of state this object would be in when I receive it in the 7th filter that I'm modifying.

There isn't much documentation. So I don't really know what state I'm getting.

Are there any other ways to replace the Pipes and Filters pattern in general?
I'm looking for a good way suitable for unit testing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/pipes-and-filters

The way this programme that I'm working on is arranged seems like each filter relies on the output of the previous filter. And the filters are added in a specific order. The filters cannot be rearranged in a different order.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to start with the modifaction request, why you did this change? Maybe there was misbehaviour of the application so you changed 7th filter to handle this. Then it would be good to mimick user actions with http client or something that caused this misbehaviour. If it's possible to mimick such user action, II would turn off the filter #7 to make the test fail, after this turn 7th filter on and test case should pass. Research the application you are modifying maybe there are already integration test cases, it might be good to do your new test in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to do an integration test from Filter#1 to Filter #11 to make sure Filter#7 works properly.

Even if a test of 1-11 passes, you are ultimately testing the output of 11, not the output of 7.

There are three basic levels of developer testing: system, integration, unit. A test of all 11 filters would be a system test, also called an end-to-end test. Testing a subset of filters together would be integration testing. Testing filter 7 alone would be unit testing.

To perform unit testing, you must mock the input to filter 7. This mock input has nothing to do with filters 1-6 and everything to do with the specification (requirements) of filter 7.

If you do not know the requirements of filter 7, you cannot unit test filter 7. Replacing the pipe-and-filter pattern will not aid in testing unknown requirements.